# hide updates in twitter

Tags: c#, twitter

i am working on the Twitter API. I am going to use C# for developing the application.

I found a more elaborated sample at http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com for using twitter API.

i need to show all tweets(Updates) of all the registered users in the application.
I have the requirement to hide some of the updates of some users from the other users both in application and Twitter.

Please suggest a solution and also some of the good reference to follow.

Comment: Please explain more. hide? how are you planning to hide? Registered users mean? Friends timeline or public time line?

Comment: Registered users are the users who registers with my application who has twitter account.


For example, i have updated status as "I am doing research" through API. I want to hide this particular status from my followers/any one and this is my main question.


For now i am searching the solution for friends timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you place on Twitter is always visible to all users. The only way to 'hide' messages from the public is to send a direct message (DM) to other people.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent your Twitter messages from being public is to set your account "protected" (Settings/Account/"Protect my tweets" checkbox), which will prevent anyone from seeing your updates until/unless you specifically allow them to have visibility.  This is, however, account-wide.  Twitter does not provide any option to protect/unprotect individual messages.  (Unless you count DMs, as already mentioned by Hilbrand, but that makes them one-to-one.  There's no way to do a group DM.)